# Syslog-ng removing special character with rewrite rule

Tags: syslog-ng

I'm trying to remove special character with syslog-ng 3.35 before sending log to log collector but without any luck. The test log I'm trying to send is shown below ( it's just a simple example to simplify):

```
(Classification cve:2019-12345)
```

I'm trying to rewrite it to get  result shown below and get rid of '(', 'Classification' and ')':

```
cve:2019-12345
```

What I was trying to do is but without success:

```
rewrite r_test {
subst("^(Classification"," ", type("string"),flags("substring"));
subst("^)"," ", type("string"),flags("substring"));
};
```

After syslog-ng restart there is no error and no wrong syntax is shown. Any ideas how to fix rule ?

Thanks in advance